# Vs 2015 Missing Intellisense for external dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I have a C# MVC 5 project that uses a custom built dll.  The dll was developed in VB.Net (VS 2015) and each function in the dll was decorated with the appropriate XML Documentation tags, including summary and parameter.  I added a reference to the dll to my C# project and it builds and runs just fine, no errors.  I can get intellisense on all the other functions used by my C# code but not the ones in my custom built dll.

I have verified that the folder containing the .dll also has an .xml file, with the exact same FileName.  And the xml file appears to be in the correct format.  I've searched the web for the past two hours trying to find a solution to this problem but have not found anything that works.  Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You say Intellisense is not working with that library but... does it compile? You mean is not showing the comment when you put the cursor on it?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Yes to all your questions.  But I just found the solution.  I closed VS 2015 and re-opened it and the intellisense was there.  Must have been somethihg I changed  but wasn't effective till VS reboot.  Thank You Microsoft!!!

Comment: You’re welcome :D

Comment: @Roger, Would you please mark your solution as the answer since it has been resolved? So it could help other community members and we could close this case. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done.  Finally found out how to mark the answer.  Its not all that obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was a wasted 2 1/2 hours. See my comment to Gonzo345.  Problem Solved.